# Dropping rows based on multiple column conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I want to subset rows based on different column conditions across several columns. For example, in the attached picture, I want my script to remove all rows that meet the following conditions:

In any of the columns (One through Five), remove rows where no valid entry is made in any of the five columns (valid entries are: poor, good, very_good, excellent). In essence, remove rows with invalid entries (invalid entries are: "NULL", "''" or contains "@")

In this example, only Chris will be excluded and others will be retained since they contain at least one valid entry across the 5 columns.[image]

Data:

```
df <-
  tibble(
    Name = c("John", "Peter", "Paul", "Joy", "Mike", "Vinc", "Ben", "Chris"),
    One = c("NULL", "@gmail", "NULL", "good", "''", "very_good", "excellent", "NULL"),
    Two = c("@yahoo", "''", "good", "good", "good", "excellent", "NULL", "''"),
    Three = c("''", "good", "very good", "poor", "excellent", "NULL", "NULL", "@gmai"),
    Four = c("good", "good", "good", "NULL", "good", "good", "good", "NULL"),
    Five = c("@gmail", "very good", "excellent", "poor", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL")
  )
```

Comment: Have some reproducible **Data**?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `dplyr::if_any` here -

```
library(dplyr)

valid_entry <- c("poor", "good", "very_good", "excellent")

df %>% filter(if_any(One:Five, ~.x %in% valid_entry))
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I do a reverse of this? List the invalids (and how do I str_detect for the @) and filter them? In the original dataset, the valid entries have over 100,000 different entries while the errors are less than 10.

Comment: Should be able to negate with `!`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

To **filter rows where *any* columns from `One` to `Five` contain** 'invalid' values:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_any(One:Five, 
                ~!str_detect(., paste0(c("poor", "good", "very_good", "excellent"), collapse = "|"))))
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  Name  One       Two    Three     Four  Five     
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <chr>    
1 John  NULL      @yahoo ''        good  @gmail   
2 Peter @gmail    ''     good      good  very good
3 Paul  NULL      good   very good good  excellent
4 Mike  ''        good   excellent good  NULL     
5 Ben   excellent NULL   NULL      good  NULL     
6 Chris NULL      ''     @gmai     NULL  NULL
```

To **filter rows where *all* columns from `One` to `Five` contain** 'invalid' values:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_all(One:Five, 
                ~!str_detect(., paste0(c("poor", "good", "very_good", "excellent"), collapse = "|"))))
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  Name  One   Two   Three Four  Five 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Chris NULL  ''    @gmai NULL  NULL
```

Data:

```
df <-
  tibble(
    Name = c("John", "Peter", "Paul", "Joy", "Mike", "Vinc", "Ben", "Chris"),
    One = c("NULL", "@gmail", "NULL", "good", "''", "very_good", "excellent", "NULL"),
    Two = c("@yahoo", "''", "good", "good", "good", "excellent", "NULL", "''"),
    Three = c("''", "good", "very good", "poor", "excellent", "NULL", "NULL", "@gmai"),
    Four = c("good", "good", "good", "NULL", "good", "good", "good", "NULL"),
    Five = c("@gmail", "very good", "excellent", "poor", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL")
  )
```

Comment: Can I filter out the rows with errors only (i.e., rows with all entries either NULL, '', or contains @?)?

Comment: Please check re-edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("John", "Peter", "Chris"),
  One  = c("NULL", "@gmail", "NULL"),
  Two = c("@yahoo", "", "@gmai"),
  Three = c("very good", "good", "NULL")
)
```

Function that checks if a row is valid or not:

```
isInvalid <- function(row) {
  row <- row[-1]                  # ignore Name
  ats <- length(grep("@", row))   # count the number of cells with "@"
  invalids <- c("NULL", "")       # list of error values
  invs <- length(which(row %in% invalids))  # count nr of error values
  (ats + invs) == length(row)               # if 'nr of ats' + 'nr of error values' is equal to the nr of cells -> invalid row
}
```

Call function for each row in the dataframe:

```
invalidrows <- apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = isInvalid)
# results in FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Extract the invalid rows from the original dataframe:

```
invalid <- df[invalidrows,]
# returns the 'Chris' row
```

Comment: Thank you. If we want to ignore more than one row - let's say we want to ignore 22 rows it should read [-1:22], right?

Comment: Also throws up an error: argument "row" is missing, with no default

Comment: The `[-1]` is for ignoring the first element/cell of the row (= Name) which we do not want to check. To ignore more elements/cells, e.g. 1 to 22, it would be `[-1:-22]` or `[-(1:22)]`.  To ignore the first 22 rows of your dataframe, you would do `df <- df[23:nrow(df),]`